# How to extract rows in a pandas dataframe NOT in a subset dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. `DF` and `SubDF`. `SubDF` is a subset of `DF`. I want to extract the rows in `DF` that are NOT in `SubDF`.

I tried the following:

```
DF2 = DF[~DF.isin(SubDF)]
```

The number of rows are correct and most rows are correct,

ie number of rows in `subDF` + number of rows in `DF2` = number of rows in `DF`

but I get rows with `NaN` values that do not exist in the original `DF`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note: the original `DF` does not have any `NaN` values, and to double check I did `DF.dropna()` before and the result still produced `NaN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `merge` with `outer join` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), because [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) need `values` and `index` match:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (DF)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

SubDF = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3],
                   'B':[6],
                   'C':[9],
                   'D':[5],
                   'E':[6],
                   'F':[3]})

print (SubDF)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  3  6  9  5  6  3
```

```
#return no match
DF2 = DF[~DF.isin(SubDF)]
print (DF2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

DF2 = pd.merge(DF, SubDF, how='outer', indicator=True)
DF2 = DF2[DF2._merge == 'left_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (DF2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, borrowing the setup from @jezrael:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

sub = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3],
                    'B':[6],
                    'C':[9],
                    'D':[5],
                    'E':[6],
                    'F':[3]})

extract_idx = list(set(df.index) - set(sub.index))
df_extract = df.loc[extract_idx]
```

The rows may not be sorted in the original df order.  If matching order is required:

```
extract_idx = list(set(df.index) - set(sub.index))
idx_dict = dict(enumerate(df.index))
order_dict = dict(zip(idx_dict.values(), idx_dict.keys()))
df_extract = df.loc[sorted(extract_idx, key=order_dict.get)]
```